# how to eliminate all the allocated charectors in javascript like "",'',{} in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a sentence how do we format that string to support and assign to a variable?

```
let words="2021-08-03 14:00:49.0430 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2021-08-03 14:00:49.4297 Info Adding target ConsoleTarget(Name=consoleLogger)
2021-08-03 14:00:49.8396 Info Found 48 configuration items
2021-08-03 14:00:49.8716 Info Configuration initialized.
2021-08-03 14:00:49.8716 Info NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.6.8.10751. Product version: 4.6.8.
{ "time": "2021-08-03 14:00:50.0625", "thread": "1", "level": "WARN", "message": "Storing keys in a directory '\/root\/.aspnet\/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.", "properties": "path=\/root\/.aspnet\/DataProtection-Keys, EventId_Id=60, EventId=60" }
{ "time": "2021-08-03 14:00:50.4593", "thread": "1", "level": "WARN", "message": "No XML encryptor configured. Key {153434f7-eab5-4326-a0aa-5973fb78b`ecb} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.", "proper`ties": "KeyId=153434f7-eab5-4326-a0aa-5973fb78becb, EventId_Id=35, EventId=35" }
{ "time": "2021-08-03 14:01:14.0448", "thread": "5", "level": "WARN", "message": "Failed to determine the https port for redirect.", "properties": "EventId_Id=3, EventId_Name=FailedToDeterminePort, EventId=FailedToDeterminePort" }"

console.log(words)
```

When I tried to do some string methods to in it its not allowing me to perform any action because of the special characters in the sentence.

How can we support this type of sentence to perform string operations?

Expected output: I should be able to get the log.

Comment: Start and end the literal with a back tic: \`2021-08 .......FailedToDeterminePort" }\`. But please edit your question and provide the expected result.

Comment: i have tried the same approach but it didnt work because its having backtick in the sentence

Comment: Then escape every backtic with a backslash. See documentation on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: The `"` inside the string must be escaped with `\"`. Learn about string escaping. You cannot do string functions on it because it is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: so formating a string is time consuming right. so can we do the same thing using files?

Comment: Escaping is only necessary in a string *literal*, not file contents. They are read into a string as-is. If your question is about reading file contents, then edit your question and show how you read the file contents into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `backtick` (`` ` ``) at **the start** and **the end** of string and add the escaping sequence `\` before any `backtick` in the middle of the text. Here is the snippet:

```js
        let words = `"2021-08-03 14:00:49.0430 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
            2021 - 08 - 03 14: 00: 49.4297 Info Adding target ConsoleTarget(Name = consoleLogger)
            2021 - 08 - 03 14: 00: 49.8396 Info Found 48 configuration items
            2021 - 08 - 03 14: 00: 49.8716 Info Configuration initialized.
2021 - 08 - 03 14: 00: 49.8716 Info NLog, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5120e14c03d0593c.File version: 4.6.8.10751.Product version: 4.6.8.
{ "time": "2021-08-03 14:00:50.0625", "thread": "1", "level": "WARN", "message": "Storing keys in a directory '\/root\/.aspnet\/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.", "properties": "path=\/root\/.aspnet\/DataProtection-Keys, EventId_Id=60, EventId=60" }
            { "time": "2021-08-03 14:00:50.4593", "thread": "1", "level": "WARN", "message": "No XML encryptor configured. Key {153434f7-eab5-4326-a0aa-5973fb78b\`ecb} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.", "proper\`ties": "KeyId=153434f7-eab5-4326-a0aa-5973fb78becb, EventId_Id=35, EventId=35" }
            { "time": "2021-08-03 14:01:14.0448", "thread": "5", "level": "WARN", "message": "Failed to determine the https port for redirect.", "properties": "EventId_Id=3, EventId_Name=FailedToDeterminePort, EventId=FailedToDeterminePort" } "
`
        console.log(words)
```